# Type Error using Positional Arguments in Matplotlib Events

Tags: python, events, matplotlib, keypress

I am trying to save files with a particular name as an `on_key_press` event in matplotlib.

Here is my code, following a matplotlib plot:

```
save_name = 'folder_name/' + file_name[12:-5]

def save_figure(event, save_name):
    if event.key == 'w':
        plt.savefig(save_name)


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', save_figure(save_name))
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: save_figure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'save_name'
```

I don't know how to pass the `save_name` variable to the `save_figure` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
save_name = 'folder_name/' + file_name[12:-5]

def save_figure(event):
    if event.key == 'w':
        plt.savefig(save_name)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', save_figure)
```

Functions can access variables in outer scopes, so `save_figure` can already access `save_name`, at least in your example code.

Answer (score 1):

you passed `save_name` as the `event` argument. `save_figure` **requires 2 arguments**. your call of `save_figure()` only has one argument. the order of the arguments also matters, too. so when you call `save_figure` it needs to look like:

```
save_figure(event,save_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the existing function, a usually employed method for such kind of problem would be to use an annonymous function.

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', lambda event: save_figure(event,save_name))
```